# "the program being debugged is not being run."

Tags: objective-c

I'm running Xcode, trying to get my app to run on my iphone. I'm getting the error message "the program being debugged is not being run."(no solution like restarting device/xcode/mac, reinstalling provisioning profile,unplug/replug device,reinstallation of app on the device works for me)

:( :(

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727169/xcode-fails-to-run-app-on-device-saying-the-program-being-debugged-is-not-being.

Comment: ya the problem is the same but none of the solutions is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ALL expired provisioning profiles (even unrelated to current app) on your device. You can do this by going to Settings app->General->Profiles (on the device), and then "Remove" the ones that show as expired. This has worked for me in the past.

Comment: that i have done my xcode have only that provisioning profile which is been used for this app.

Comment: I meant remove all the expired provisioning profiles on your device (iPhone, iPad, ...), not in XCode.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've solved the problem. What worked for me was to set all linked libraries (one of them was still set to simulator and/or distribution) to the same build configurations.

Answer (score 0):

change provisioning profile select through **Info** 
I changed selected provisioning profile from Ad-Hoc to Developer and the problem solved.