# Overwriting an iPhone app from a different Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, project, overwrite

One of the apps I've developed is submitted and approved to the appstore.
Because of some big changes and a more generic code I created a new XCode project for this app.

The problem is when trying to install the same app (based on bundle identifier) from the new XCode project, it quits with a crash. If I try to install again (Build & Run/Debug) from XCode, it seems to successfully overwrite and run. So it seems the first time there are some merge / overwrite conflicts. A second install, over the failed first attempt makes it work.

I wouldn't want this to happen with app updates downloaded from the store.

I've read that the idea is not to build from XCode, but use an Ad Hoc Build through iTunes instead. This would simulate a more natural end-user process. I've tried this, but somehow it won't sync / overwrite the existing app from the appstore (no errors, the app is just not changing).

Does someone have a hint on how to solve this?
Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem all the time.  I use one Developer Profile for all my dev work (and thus, one bundle identifier).

You have to delete the old App from the phone, and do a Clean Build.

These are similar problems. [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727169/xcode-fails-to-run-app-on-device-saying-the-program-being-debugged-is-not-being) [(2)](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/promotion-techniques/28823-error-debugger-program-being-debugged-not-being-run.html)

Comment: This might work as a solution on the developer end, but this is not an option for end-users. The idea of an app-update should not be to delete it first.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems working with an Ad Hoc build through iTunes does work.
Yesterday I double-clicked, but never got the iTunes message warning me of an older version existing in my apps and whether I want to replace it.

Dragging the .IPA into the iTunes app section did give me this message. Telling it to replace and next syncing works okay. iTunes sync status bar displays the message "YourAppName Updating". Afterwards launching it works fine with stored data intact.

The flow described here worked for me:
[How to test an iPhone application update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524326/how-to-test-an-iphone-application-update/3079092#3079092)