# Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 3595

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4, ad-hoc-distribution

When I try to run my app on my device with ad hoc distribution profile from XCode 4, I get:
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 3595.

The app does load onto the device though and works fine if I launch it from there. 
Yes, 'Can be debugged' is set to NO in Entitlements.plist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488600/iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process

Answer (score 18):

Usually it wont load while with ad hoc profile .You need to debug and can debug only with development profile.

Comment: my problem with code signing was that I was selecting the wrong one at the last step of exporting the code (NOT in the build settings page)

Answer (score 3):

You can't debug apps signed with the distribution (even adhoc) provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are fake Code Signing

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqDVXh2S1P0