# Not able to load the app in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am getting the following error

> " Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process
>   521."

Which does not allow the application to run ,(in debugger) dont know what the issue is.
If someone has came across the same issue please help.

Comment: Did you tried restarting the simulator?

Comment: @ iSharreth i am installing on the device and tried restarting the xcode as well as iphone also but it didnt helped ..

Comment: this can be help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488600/iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me like you are trying to debug an app where you have set `get-allows-task` to `NO` in your `Entitlements.plist` file (*for instance, for a Ad Hoc build*).

Does your project have an `Entitlements.plist` file? If so, check the value of `get-allows-task`. If you are running the `Debug` configuration, this must be set to `YES`

If you open the file by single clicking on it, so it's displayed in the property list editor rather than the code editor then the required parameter is (*confusingly*) named `Can be debugged`

[image: Entitlements.plist]

Edit: Added screenshot to show where **Code Signing Entitlements** can be found

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for quick response but i dont know from where can we set that get-allows-task to NO.

Comment: In your Xcode project, look to see if you have a file called `Entitlements.plist` or `Entitlements.entitlements`. If you do you can just click on it to open it in the code editor and then look for the line that says `Can be debugged`, once you've found it click to the right where the drop-down is and change it's value to `YES`

Comment: hey thanks i did that, but did not helped and mnay thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Can you tell me, or add a screenshot to your question showing what is listed under the **Code Signing Entitlements** section of your build settings? (*I've added a screenshot above to show where you can see them*)

Comment: hey i did make the changes but still could not make the figure out  the error , can i get your email id i will send the code on that id is that fine.

Comment: I'd prefer not to post my email address here as it'll be ripe for picking by spam bots. However, I'm happy to take a look at your code if you upload it to something like [CloudApp](http://getcloudapp.com/) or [GitHub](http://github.com) or any other sharing service you prefer and then post the link here.

Comment: I have downloaded it from http://tutorials.simplesdk.com/in-app-purchase.html . Just download it and try  to have  look why i am not able to debug this code .It happen then when i debug this code it runs for about 5 t 10 seconds and then above error.