# Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process on xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2, jailbreak

I'm having some problems debugging apps directly on my iphone. I'm using xcode 4.2 and a jailbroken ios 5.0.1 device and when trying to launch the app on my iphone from excode I get the following message: "Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process (some number here)" But if I now try to use the app directly on the iphone it works perfectly.
Does anyone know how to fix it? thank you.

Comment: Jailbroken devices have one big problem. They are Jailbroken. However you can refer to this question for more help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1488600/277021

Comment: I've read it already but I don't know how to do what they are telling me to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For xcode 4:
you have to create Entitlements.plist file from menu->File->New->New File->Code Signing->Entitlemens. it is going to be create Entitlements.Plist in your application folder

and Targets->build Settings->Code Signing Entitlements, you have click here two time and write  "Entitlements.plist"

I did this and xcode don not get anymore error