# failed to get the task process - test application xcode to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.3

I'm currently a student in computer engineering/development, and I started developing an iPhone application. I have a jailbroken iPhone 4S iOS 5.1.1, and a Macbook Air 2012 with Xcode 4.3.3

I have read/seen a lot of tutorials on how to test an application on a device without having a developer account on Apple Developers (I'm just a student and don't want to spend 99$ for testing an application that will not be put on the App Store, I just want to learn).

I followed all the steps (edit SDKsettings.plist, don't sign the code on build settings...), the application works fine on the iPhone simulator, but when I want to test it on my iPhone, the application appears on the springboard, but when I launch it, it crashes instantly, and on Xcode I have a message on the debug area saying :

```
> error: failed to launch
> '/Users/amine/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mes_horaires_de_travail-dfzorjqmnecsnafvctvhgsuphwws/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/Mes
> horaires de travail.app/Mes horaires de travail' -- failed to get the
> task for process 28720
```

This is not the first application that crashes on launch.
Can anyone help me with this error ? I found [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777080/error-launching-remote-program-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process-on-xcode-4-2), but I don't have the menu on Xcode to create Entitlements.plist to test the solution.

Thanks a lot.

P.S : please be kind, I'm just a beginner... ^_^

Answer (score 10):

Change your development profile to Debug not Release. You can't test on your device with a release profile.

Comment: I have changed all properties from Release to Debug, I also changed Scheme settings (Product > Edit scheme) for my iPhone, but still not working :(

Can you please tell me if I need to post something here or change any other setting ? Please explain to me how to post something because I don't know how to :)

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but the googles showed me this page so for future reference:

I've got the same problem recently even though I was running in debug mode, however codesigning errors had me experimenting with code signing identities and the one for the debugging profile was still pointing to the adhoc profile instead of the development profile.

Once I changed them the error vanished.