# Weird error when trying to run a test on device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

For almost a week i'm getting this weird error when i'm trying to run the app on my idevice. 
the error is that:

```
error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 10492
```

It's important to say that I get this message on Xcode, the app quites on the idevice, but right after I can run it by clicking on the app icon and it works just fine with the latest updates.

what seems to be the problem?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have set the build configuration in Release mode, and installing the application in device through Xcode. If you want to debug the app, then you should go to Edit scheme, and choose Debug mode. Also, make sure, you have a developer profile, and that you are building with that developer profile. Then, when you try to install the app through Xcode, you will see the app getting installed. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

GDB is having trouble attaching to the device process. Have you tried restarting the device?

If this is a permanent issue and you have an Entitlements.plist file have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488600/iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process).

Answer (score 1):

Please check your certificates. If you are signing with distribution certificate then you will not able to debug. To debug you have to have provision certificate

Hope this will help