# How to resolve error "failed to get the task for process 2196" when trying to run app on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I'm testing the in App Purchase on device but when I tried to run the app on device, it displays error `failed to get the task for process 2196`.

I have encountered this error before but at that time I have changed my Provision profile and developer certificate and its worked but I can't do that with this app. because of the in app purchase.

Any suggestion that how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Clear all your preferences from xcode and delete your app from device and restart your device. clean and build your project. i think this may help to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488600/iphone-debugging-how-to-resolve-failed-to-get-the-task-for-process

Comment: @san no, In his accepted answer problem with plist but in my app i have not added any plist rather than info.plist. And other answers suggest to change certificate and provisioning profile which also i cant do bcoz of inapp purchase

Comment: You are getting the same error, which is related to get-task-allow or "Can be debugged" property. Please see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1682/_index.html. The Entitlement.plist can be the cause of this as specified in the link I provided. I dont think your issue is related to in-app purchase, though I would love to learn this new thing if it is really related.

Comment: @san issue is not related to inapp purchase its definitely becoz of the Provision profile or Certificate. and thanx for the link i will check it and let you know.

Comment: @Maul where do i clear the preference?

Comment: Go in xcode menu select preferences then select derived data and delete all inside that folder

Comment: @Maul Now i am getting `failed to get the task for process 170` error and app closed.

Comment: You are getting the "failed to get the task for process" error message because you are either using your Ad Hoc or Distribution Provisioning profile when debugging your iPhone application on your device or you specified a code signing entitlements property list in your build settings which does not include a get-task-allow or "Can be debugged" property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to create separate developer `provisioning` profile with enable `inApp Parchase`. I think you are trying to use same testing developer provisioning profile with your current app. Follow this step:-

- Create a new App ID in the Provisioning Portal
- Create a Development Provisioning Profile using the new AppID
- Create a new App in iTunes Connect. Enter the basic info but Do Not upload a binary. Do Not click the 'Ready to Upload Binary' button.
- Create an In App Purchase Product for the App. The status for the Product should be 'Approved by Developer'
- In iTunes Connect, return to the App Details and add your new In App Purchase Product to the In App Purchases section of the App Details.
  Run the project from XCode, using the Development Provisioning Profile you created.

Comment: But i have another issue related to this. I have created developer provisioning profile and its worked in-app working. But how can i send the app to my client for testing without distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: if your client want to test build then just sent IPA file as we did normally and create one testUserAccound from Itunes Connect. and give that test user id password to client.

Comment: Sorry for my less knowledge but isn't the Distribution provisioning profile is compulsory for ad hoc distribution?

Comment: distribution provisioning only need while you are going to submit app in appstore.